# Villarceau circles of the square torus

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, manifolds

I'm talking of ordinary tori in 3D (donuts). According to a paper I read and my understanding, "the" square torus is the torus with $R/r = \sqrt{2}$ (where $R$ and $r$ are the major and the minor radii).

- Why is it called "square"?
- Is is true that two Villarceau circles on the square torus meet at a right angle?
- If this is true, do you have a reference for this fact? I googled with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking holomorphically, a *torus* is obtained from quotienting the Euclidean plane by a lattice. Two tori are equivalent if and only if their lattices are similar (one is a non-zero complex multiple of the other).

A *square* torus comes from the lattice of Gaussian integers, $\mathbf{Z} + i\mathbf{Z}$, or another square lattice.

Assume $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers satisfying $a^{2} + b^{2} = 1$. A rectangular torus (i.e., whose lattice is rectangular) with aspect ratio $b/a$ may be obtained in two steps: Parametrize the flat torus in the three-sphere
$$
T(u, v) = (a\cos u, a\sin u, b\cos v, b\sin v),
$$
then map to Euclidean three-space by stereographic projection from $(0, 0, 0, 1)$:
$$
X(u, v) = \frac{1}{1 - b\sin v}(a\cos u, a\sin u, b\cos v).
$$
The flat torus parametrization is a local isometry from the Euclidean plane and stereographic projection from the three-sphere is conformal, so this parametrization is conformal.

If $a = b = 1/\sqrt{2}$, the preceding formula is a conformal parametrization of a square torus.

Villarceau circles are images of lines of slope $\pm1$ in the Euclidean plane, so *yes, they meet at right angles*.

<>

You may enjoy this [interactive web program](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/%7Eahwang/teach/software/Torus/index.html) for drawing on a square torus. (Usage instructions are at the bottom of the linked page.) Particularly, you can test the claim about Villarceau circles by drawing diagonal lines.

Comment: Thanks. When you claim that Villarceau circles are the images of lines with slope $\pm 1$, this is the case only for the square torus, right?

Comment: Yes; for a rectangular torus they're images of lines parallel to the diagonals of a fundamental rectangle.